# combining of two images in Android

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I want to combine two images by overlapping them at some fixed x-axis displacement. Suppose There are two images and both are the left and right snaps of the same panoramic view ,

1. Now the problem is to find the X -axis displacement of the right
   image overlapping the left one so that both pixels match and they
   form the panoramic view.
2. The next issue is how they can be merged so that they feel like a single image without any defect.

I have to do this using android , but please tell me using java /android how this can be done.

Comment: you have image which is vertically divided or horizontally??

Comment: Suppose That image is vertically divided... but in real both are the two different images taken at different time ... but both images are the left and right portion of a same view .so the problem is to find the displacement so that the pixel mathches

Comment: not side by side but by overlapping one image over other ... because the right portion of the left image and left portion of the right image shall be same ... so the issue is to find the amount of x axis displacement so that the lower and upper(overlapped) pixels after displacement match exactly to form another big image

Comment: give marginLeft to the right image negative as android:marginleft="-10dp".it will overlap the left image

Comment: Akash You are not getting the problem . Suppose  while moving the camera in horizontal direction you clicked two images . now both images are the same part of the scene ..( and The first one's right and second one's left would have the common distribution of pixels as both are common ... now the problem is to find that common part and their displacement so that when both images are merged they form a bigger image ...programmatically ... please tell me any solution if you have

Comment: You can use AlphaComposite.SrcOver to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

The problem is complex. Note that each picture is a projection of word on plane. For each photo you can assume that point of projection is same but plane of projection is different. This means that common parts on each photo are distorted (bended) in different way.
This means that transition between photos is not linear and simple transition is not enough!

[here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4670/2010fa/projects/final/results/group_of_acc269_ty244_yc563/cs4670_final.html) you can find better description of the problem.